# Outer join and aggregation between two tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to aggregate a number of car crashes, where each crash is given a unique id, as well as being assigned to one or more street segments (a segment is like a street block), so:

```
crashid | segment1 | segment2 | segment3 | segment4
---------------------------------------------------
001       1          2          3          4
002       4          5          6          7
003       4
```

The second table contains a 'corridor', which is a set of segment ids. The corridors are disjoint, i.e. contain no overlapping street segments:

```
corridor | segmentid
--------------------
A          4
A          7
A          10
B          11
B          12
...
```

A map would look like:

```
   3|   5 |    8|
    |     |     |
1---|--4--|--7--|--10--
    |     |     |
   2|    6|    9|
```

So, I'd like to get the sum of crashes that occurred in each corridor. For corridor A, this is a count of crash id's that contain either segment 4, 7, or 10.

Comment: It looks like the first table isn't properly normalized. Is there anything, logically, different between a `4` appearing in `segment4` for one crash versus it appearing in `segment1` for another crash - and if so, will you ever want to be able to query for e.g. "adjoining" segments? If so, that table structure will make such queries increasingly difficult to write.

Comment: which platform are you doing this on?

Comment: No, there isn't anything logically different. Some crash entries may be listed with identical segments, in a different order, but would be attributed to the same "intersection"

Comment: This is a database in MS Access

Comment: Do you have a fixed numbner of segment columns?

Comment: you don't say the table names

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select crashid
  from cor
  join crash on crash.segement1 = cor.segmentid
  where cor.corridor = @incorridor
  union all 
  select crashid
  from cor
  join crash on crash.segement2 = cor.segmentid
  where cor.corridor = @incorridor
  union all 
  select crashid
  from cor
  join crash on crash.segement3 = cor.segmentid
  where cor.corridor = @incorridor
  union all 
  select crashid
  from cor
  join crash on crash.segement4 = cor.segmentid
  where cor.corridor = @incorridor
)
```